# Cannot find the Nagios binary or no execute permissions in NagiosQL

Tags: apache, centos, nagios

I downloaded `nagiosql_320.tar.gz` and installed NagiosQL. When I click on check configuration file, it shows error as:

> Cannot find the Nagios binary or no execute permissions!

I created symlink as below for nagios binary with following permission.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Jul  5 16:07 /usr/sbin/nagios -> /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios

-rwxr-x--- 1 nagios apache 692624 Jun 27 14:40 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios
```

How can I correct the error?

Comment: can you provide the output of ls -lsa /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios please?

Answer (score 0):

`chmod +x /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios` and try again

Comment: After did this still the same issue having and I am using CentOS 7